# How can I use SqlDataReader to get grouped data returned by a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a sproc that is defined by

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetQuestionsGroupedBySection
    @survey_id INT
AS
    SELECT S.title, Q.qtext
    FROM Sections AS S INNER JOIN Questions AS Q 
         ON S.id = Q.section_id
         WHERE S.survey_id = @survey_id
         GROUP BY S.title;
```

where the relevant tables are defined by

```
CREATE TABLE Questions (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    section_id INT,
    qtext NVARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (section_id) REFERENCES Sections(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Sections (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    title NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    survey_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (survey_id) REFERENCES Surveys(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Now I'm trying to call that from my server-side code to get the groupings in a `List` of elements of type

```
public class QuestionsBySection
{
    public string SectionTitle { get; set; }
    public List<string> SecionQuestions;
}
```

(or is there a better data structure to use?). What I have is

```
    public List<QuestionsBySection> GetQuestionsAndSection (int survid)
    {
        // survid: survey id
        List<QuestionsBySection> AllQuestions = new List<QuestionsBySection>();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetQuestionsGroupedBySection", this._Conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@survey_id", survid);
            this._Conn.Open();
            using ( SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
            {
                while ( dataReader.Read() )
                {
                    // ... 
                }
            }
            this._Conn.Close();
        }
        return AllQuestions;
    }
```

but I'm not sure how to fill in the `// ...`. Any hints?

Comment: Your stored procedure does not seem to be valid SQL (missing grouping or aggregate on Q.qtext)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I have `GROUP BY S.title;`

Comment: SQL Server gives `Column 'Questions.qtext' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause` when I try to create the procedure. Only MySQL would allow you to select a field without aggregation or grouping on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sql group by is wrong**

You have 2 columns in the results, but only 1 in the group. You can either add the second column as a group by field or use an agregate (eg min() or max()).

```
SELECT S.title, qtext=max(Q.qtext)
    FROM .....
```

**DataReader**

Just use the field position as an index parameter to GetString:

```
var sTitle = dataReader.GetString(0);
var sQuestion = dataReader.GetString(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query is invalid with SQL Server; when using a group by clause, all fields selected must either be included in the group by clause or be an aggregate. Based on your expected results, there are a couple of ways of returning a collection of `QuestionsBySection`.

One option is to return the result set flattened out and then aggregate on the app tier.

The SProc should remove the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT S.title, Q.qtext
FROM Sections AS S INNER JOIN Questions AS Q 
    ON S.id = Q.section_id
WHERE S.survey_id = @survey_id
```

When retrieved, each row needs to be evaluated to see if the Title has already been used:

```
var questions = new List<QuestionsBySection>();
// create sql connection
// execute command

while (dataReader.Read())
{
    string title = dataReader.GetString("title");
    string question = dataReader.GetString("qtext");

    QuestionsBySection qbs = questions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SectionTitle.Equals(title , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    if (qbs != null)
    {
        qbs.SecionQuestions.Add(question);
        continue;
    }

    qbs = new QuestionsBySection
    {
        SectionTitle = title,
        SecionQuestions = new List<string>{ question }
    }
    questions.Add(qbs);
}
```

There are several other ways of achieving the result, but this should give you a better understanding of how to aggregate the results.